# How common is the expression "with the come of ..."? Is there a better equivalent?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I was reading a text on the internet and I came across something like this written by a non-native guy:

> With the come of the new methods/procedures, we can perform [whatever]
>   faster.

1. Is it natural to say "with the come of ..."?
2. What other ways are there to imply the same meaning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "...the _coming_."

Comment: @Rattler Yeah that sounds better, thanks. (I knew there is something wrong with that sentence lol)

Comment: There are probably better words to use.

Comment: @Rattler I'd appreciate it if you could name a few

Comment: Maybe _arrival_, or _implementation_?

Comment: @Rattler OR _appearance_ or _introduction_?

Comment: A nice phrase, albeit more formal, is *With the advent of ...*

Answer (score -1):

Another way to say "with the come of" is "with the **advent** of" (*advent* descends etymologically from a word that means "come", according to [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=advent)):

> **advent** noun [ S ] uk /ˈæd.vent/ /ˈæd.vənt/ us /ˈæd.vent/ /ˈæd.vənt/ the fact of an event happening, an invention being made, or a person arriving:
>
> "Life was transformed by the advent of the steam engine."
>
> "The advent of the gramophone transformed the cultural conditions of contemporary music, including the way it was taught."

Or "with the emergency of", from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4433644/

> Recently, **with the emergency** of microarray technology that can monitor thousands of genes simultaneously, gene biomarkers are being detected for oral cancers. For example, Saintigny et al. [2] defined a 29-transcripts signature while Kondoh et al. [3] defined another 11-genes signature that can help separate oral cancers developed from OLKs from normal OLKs.

Comment: Neither I nor my nearest dictionary know this meaning of "emergency". Are you sure it wasn't a typo (in the linked paper) for "emergence"?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, it was an automatic suggestion by https://ludwig.guru/s/with+the+emergency+of , truth be told. However, the same search revealed more than one instance. Still, "emergence" _does_ seem to be a better fit. Should I edit?